# Link dynamic C runtime with clang (windows)

Tags: c++, c, windows, clang

Clang on windows (using msvc libs) links with `libcmt` (the static runtime library) by default. Is there an easy way to link with the dynamic library (`msvcrt`)?

Normally, clang adds `-defaultlib:libcmt` to the linker command, which links the program to the static runtime. This occurrs even if the source file is blank.

The way I've found you can is by adding the options `-Wl,-nodefaultlib:libcmt -D_DLL -lmsvcrt` to override the default. However, this seems quite awkward. Is there a better way of linking the dynamic runtime than this?

Comment: At least I didn't found a better way. Thanks for `-Wl,-nodefaultlib:libcmt -D_DLL -lmsvcrt`. That's what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 4):

If you use clang-cl, the regular /MT / /MD flags work.

Comment: Unfortunately, clang-cl.exe may not be compatible with everyone's build systems. Switching to clang-cl.exe may be non-trivial.

Comment: Regular clang doesn't add libcmt by default, so you can just pass `msvcrt.lib` (or `libcmt.lib`) normally. If you con't use `clang-cl` you don't have the problem of clang-cl automatically adding `libcmt` :)

Comment: If that were true then clang wouldn't succeed at linking anything that used crt functions unless you specified one.  It doesn't fail.  It links libcmt[d].lib by default.  You can verify this by creating a hello world and running dumpbin /DIRECTIVES on it.

Comment: @MichaelLabbé what specific output of dumpbin /directives you mean to look at ? or was that dumpbin /dependents ?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem and found I had to link against msvcrt, vcruntime and ucrt. See this post for more information https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/introducing-the-universal-crt/.