# select msvc runtime when using clang on windows

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, clang, clang++

I am currently try to compile a larger project using MSVC and clang via Makefiles. The project contains several static, shared libraries and executables.
Compiling the project with clang under Linux and using NDK (Windows/Linux) works quit well. Now I am trying to compile the whole Project on Windows.

What I did

- install LLVM 14.0.5
- install Visual Studio Community 2022
- setup makefiles to use LLVM for windows
- makefiles are referencing to Windows Kit to ensure a Windows SDK + using link.exe through lld-link.exe

The problem is that clang selects msvcrt runtime (MSVC /MT[d] switch) but I need to compile the projects to use runtime provided by MSVC /MD[d] switch.
My question is, how can I select the runtime either through compile flag or by having some pre-processor define or someting else?

```
lld-link: error: /failifmismatch: mismatch detected for 
RuntimeLibrary':
>>> test.cpp.o has value MTd_StaticDebug
>>> libDxBc.lib(api.obj) has value MDd_DynamicDebug
```

libDxBc.lib was build using visual studio
link command

```
lld-link.exe @linker.list libDxBc.lib  -ignore:LNK4217 -libpath:"c:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community"/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.32.31326/lib/x64 -libpath:"C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10"/Lib/10.0.20348.0/ucrt/x64 -libpath:"C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10"/Lib/10.0.20348.0/um/x64 -machine:x64 -subsystem:console -nodefaultlib msvcrtd.lib vcruntime.lib ucrtd.lib legacy_stdio_definitions.lib legacy_stdio_wide_specifiers.lib oldnames.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib vcomp.lib rpcrt4.lib wsock32.lib setupapi.lib imagehlp.lib winmm.lib Shlwapi.lib   -dll -out:test.dll -implib:test.lib -def:test.def
```

Looks like the information is part of the compile process so  test.cpp.o contains this information

**SOLUTION**

- define -D_DLL for compile
- link using -nodefaultlib msvcrtd.lib vcruntime.lib ucrtd.lib

Comment: Pass the `/MD` switch to the compiler?

Comment: I would say this is a clang-cl switch and not for clang++. I am already passing -MD which is part of the dependency file generation. So I guess -MD and /MD are the same ...

Comment: /MD provides this error -> clang++: error: no such file or directory: '/MD'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41850296/link-dynamic-c-runtime-with-clang-windows

Comment: yeah this is the linker part. but the compiler seems to add /failifmismatch:RuntimeLibrary=MTd_StaticDebug inside the obj file